Why doesn't Safari render certain sides of my 3d cube?
I've created a simple rotating 3D cube:
3d Cube
The problem is that on Safari only the front and back sides of the cube are showing.

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>3D Rotating Cube</title>
<style>
  .cube-container {
    perspective: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 100px auto;
  }

.cube {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: rotateCube 5s infinite linear;
}

  .face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 2px solid #000;
  }

  .front  { transform: translateZ(100px); }
  .back   { transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px); }
  .right  { transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px); }
  .left   { transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }
  .top    { transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px); }
  .bottom { transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }

  @keyframes rotateCube {
    0%   { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="cube-container">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="face front">Front</div>
    <div class="face back">Back</div>
    <div class="face right">Right</div>
    <div class="face left">Left</div>
    <div class="face top">Top</div>
    <div class="face bottom">Bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

The left and right sides of the cube are invisible. In other browsers it works normally. I'm using Safari 17. Why does Safari has a problem rendering sides of my 3d cube and can I fix it somehow?

I cannot remember exactly which browser did what. But there is no description of how to handle pixel-rounding in W3C. So the one browser does round up percentages in pixel, the other does round down. Hope that helps.

I did this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/c059wrf7/ . Does it work?

I see all sides in safari 17. MacOS 12. Intel chip.

@deER Alas it still hides the left/right side of the cube

@Kokodoko I'm using Version 17.4.1 (18618.1.15.111.8, 18618) of Safari on an iMac with M1 and osX Ventura

I also tested with safari 17.4.1 on a M1 macbook, and still I see all sides. Maybe you enabled/disabled something under "Developer > Feature flags" ?

@Kokodoko Not to my knowledge. I even pressed the 'reset feature flags' button. Also read somewhere that this is likely MacOS Ventura related and that Safari 17 on Ventura isn't rendering those sides correctly. Don't know how true that is.

One think I did discover is that when I change those degrees from 90deg to anything close to that, like 89.9deg, then the sides are showing. It seems to have a problem with sides that are rotated exactly 90deg. Failing to render them when the rotation animation starts.
